# Mosquito: how to detect when device has been unplugged

Tags: connection, device, detection, mosquitto

Using the [mosquito library](http://mosquitto.org) is there a way to **detect when a device has been unplugged**?

In the **mosquitto.c** (from library version 1.2.3) file I have found this disconnect function callback:

```
void mosquitto_disconnect_callback_set(struct mosquitto *mosq, void (*on_disconnect)(struct mosquitto *, void *, int))
```

However the above function **is not called when the device is unplugged**.

Any suggestion on which callback I should use to detect this? (Assuming that there actually is **a callback function** that detects this)

Answer (score 0):

The disconnect callback will be called as soon as the client library knows that the disconnect has occurred. The amount of time this takes depends on the `keepalive` parameter if your OS doesn't tell the library sooner.